# Calculate $P(X>Y^2)$

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Calculate $P(X>Y^2)$ given that $$f(x,y)=6(x-y)$$ for all $(x,y)$ such as $$0\le y\le x\le1$$

My solution: $$6\cdot\int_{0}^{y^2}\int_{0}^{x}(x-y)dydx$$ 
which in turn results in : $y^6$. However I have no way of knowing whether or not I have actually solved this correctly and hence arrived at the right answer. Is my solution correct? and how do I verify my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the graph:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image: ![enter image description here]

The total probability is:
$$P(\underbrace{0\le Y\le X\le 1}_{\text{the gray region}})=P(0\le Y\le X \ \cap \ 0\le X\le 1)=\int_0^1\int_0^x6(x-y)dydx=1.$$
The required probability is:
$$P(X>Y^2)=P(Y^2<X)=P(0\le Y^2<X\le 1)=P(\underbrace{0\le Y<\sqrt{X}\le 1}_{\text{the gray and orange regions altogether}})=\\
P(\underbrace{0\le Y\le X\le 1}_{\text{the gray region}})+P(\underbrace{0\le \color{red}{X< Y}\le \sqrt{X}\le 1}_{\text{the orange region}})=1+0=1,$$
because:
$$f(x,y)=0, \color{red}{X<Y} \Rightarrow P(X<Y)=0.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Farruhota. Did you make a mistake when expressing the orange region? shouldn't it have been $P(0 \le Y\le \sqrt{X}\le 1)$ instead?

Comment: Nope, the orange region is betweem the curve $y=\sqrt{x}$ and the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 2):

This probability is equal to  $1$. This is because $$\Pr\{X>Y\}=1\overbrace{\implies}^{0\le Y^2\le Y\le 1} \Pr\{X>Y^2\}=1 $$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Mostafa! though i don't fully comprehend how you have arrived at this solution. Would you care to elaborate further on your answer. And in the event of being asked to find the $P(X\le Y^2)$  will your answer still hold true? Is there an obvious way to verify one's answer.

Comment: You're welcome Reddevil. Sure I will elaborate my answer anywhere you needed. Based on the information of the question $X$ is always greater than $Y$. In the mathematical literature, this means that the probability of $X$ being greater than $Y$ is $1$. This is like asking such a question like: **We know the ${1\over 2}$ is greater that $1\over 3$. Is then, ${1\over 2}>({1\over 3})^2$?** where the answer is: *of course*. This is the same outline I also used in here.